# Apple Inc. using OpenGL ES

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

For which purposes does Apple use **OpenGL ES 1.0/1.1** and for which other purposes is **OpenGL ES 2.0** in use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use OpenGL ES 2.0 on device that support it, older models of the iPhone (orginal and 3G) and iPod Touch ( 1g and 2g) do not support OpenGL ES 2.0.

OpenGL ES 1.1 is available on all devices.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL ES 1.0/1.1 was supported with the original iPhone due to processor limitations. As processors evolved within the devices OpenGL ES 2.0 became available to developers to use. I believe the cut off for OpenGL ES 2.0 is the iPhone 3GS.

Comment: according to this list the iphone 4S uses both versions: http://www.khronos.org/conformance/adopters/conformant-products#topengles

Comment: OpenGL ES 1.0/1.1 is supported on all devices. But 2.0 has limits on what devices it can be used on.

Comment: @p0rter - Also for the devices which support OpenGL ES 2.0 (which is 95+% of active devices out there now), 1.1 is effectively implemented on top of 2.0 (1.1 fixed function capabilities are performed by shaders, etc.).